# MySQL: How many rows have a same number as the current row has?

Tags: sql, mariadb

There is mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.64-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) 
table as

```
date        number
2020-01-01  123
2020-01-02  123
2020-01-03  123
2020-01-04  123
2020-01-05  123
2020-01-07  456
2020-01-08  456
2020-01-15  456
2020-01-16  456
2020-01-07  789
2020-01-10  789
2020-01-11  789
```

How to get

```
date        number  count_before
2020-01-01  123     0
2020-01-02  123     1
2020-01-03  123     2
2020-01-04  123     3
2020-01-05  123     4
2020-01-07  456     0
2020-01-08  456     1    
2020-01-15  456     2
2020-01-16  456     3
2020-01-07  789     0
2020-01-10  789     1
2020-01-11  789     2
```

where count_before is how many rows have a same number as the current row has (exclude current row)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select 
    t.*,
    row_number() over(partition by number order by date) - 1 count_before
from mytable t
```

In MariaDB < 10.3, another option is a correlated subquery:

```
select
    t.*,
    (select count(*) from mytable t1 where t1.number = t.number and t1.date < t.date) count_before
from mytable t
```

This query would take advantage of an index on `(number, date)`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an old version of MariaDB.  Quite old.  One that doesn't support window functions.

One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*) from t t2 where t2.number = t.number and t2.date < t.date) as count_before
from t;
```

With an index on `(number, date)` and not too many dates per number (say no more than a dozen or two), this should even have reasonable performance.  Plus, the code is view-safe.